# Selenium Webdriver Java: Find element in drop-down with dynamic div[] number in xpath

Tags: java, regex, selenium, xpath

Using TestNG and @Factory annotation
I am trying to click element in drop-down menu, but when I add more than two parameters in DataProvider (test is running 3 times in a row, for example), following error appears in test runner:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[61]/ul/li[15]/label"}

So first two times xpath was found:
Xpath = /html/body/div[61]/ul/li[15]/label

But the third time it was changed to:
Xpath = /html/body/div[**62**]/ul/li[15]/label

How can I cover this case using regex in selenium (Java)?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML to your question please? Would help us answer the question with a suitable xpath.

Comment: Along with html, it would be good if you can attach respective image as well. Please edit the question to do so.

Comment: `code`<li class=" ">
 <label for="ui-multiselect-69-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover">
  <input id="ui-multiselect-69-option-2" name="multiselect_69" type="radio" value="9" title="American">
   <span>
  American
   </span>
 </label>
</li>`code`

Comment: Screenshot: https://s16.postimg.org/jhxuvsopx/stack_screen.png